# Google Maps SDK for iOS Runtime warning - Core Date Failed to Load Optimised Path

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, core-data, ios9, google-maps-sdk-ios

Ever since upgrading my google maps sdk for iOS to 1.10.3 (currently the most recent SDK version), I'm getting this warning:

2015-09-16 16:13:12.492 Tripnary[377:58694] CoreData: Failed to load optimized model at path '/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/E89C9132-91BA-4864-8589-147851DCDD64/Tripnary.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/Storage.omo'

2015-09-16 16:13:12.497 Tripnary[377:58694] CoreData: Failed to load optimized model at path '/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/E89C9132-91BA-4864-8589-147851DCDD64/Tripnary.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/Storage.omo'

2015-09-16 16:13:12.502 Tripnary[377:58694] CoreData: Failed to load optimized model at path '/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/E89C9132-91BA-4864-8589-147851DCDD64/Tripnary.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/Storage.omo'

2015-09-16 16:13:12.508 Tripnary[377:58694] CoreData: Failed to load optimized model at path '/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/E89C9132-91BA-4864-8589-147851DCDD64/Tripnary.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/Storage.omo'

Comment: this issue had been reported in the [Google Maps API public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8459), seems the issue has not been fixed yet, some people have workarounds, but you might wait for new official updates.

Comment: It's now Oct 6th. When the h is this gonna be fixed?

Comment: looks like as of the Oct 5, they are able to recreate the issue and working on a fix but nothing yet

Comment: got same error and i just used sdk by today but as you can say oct 6th that fix but no that not fix yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this [was fixed](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8459) today, in 1.10.4.

FYI, it didn't cause any problems as far as I concern, other than the message on the log.

Comment: 2 years later, it's happening again. :D

Comment: Yep, happening again!

Comment: is there any fix