# CoreData: annotation: Failed to load optimized model at path with Xcode 9 GM

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, xcode9

## Failed to load OMO warning (potential crash):

Project with xcode 9 following warning is observed in the console during debug/release builds (iOS 11 GM/beta & iOS 10):

```
CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path "/Users/xyz.abc/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A-GUID/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B-GUID/app-name.app/Frameworks/framework-name/mystorename.momd/mystorename 6.omo"
```

Any custom framework (e.g. GoogleMaps, etc) that uses CD also results in this warning and potential crashes.

## Update: Using Xcode11, noticed similar issue with DTDeviceKitBase.framework:

`CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/Applications/Xcode11.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/Versions/A/Resources/CrashDatabaseModel.momd/CrashDatabaseModel-5.0.1.omo'`

## Note:

- Also noticed this with modal used in *app* and other framework. For app, clean build results in this error. Path shown in warning points to model used with app and not a framework.
- Compilation with previous Xcode do work fine and no warning is noticed.

## Tried following:

1. complete clean build
2. ensured omo exists in datamodel v6, ManagedObjectModel & PersistentStoreCoordinator are non-nil. All functionality works as expected.
3. add newer version of datamodel v7, ensured omo v7 exists -- clean builds & device deployment
4. added schema again

Please add suggestions.
What are the potential implications of this warning?

## Related:

1. https://openradar.appspot.com/33212613
2. https://openradar.appspot.com/33573724
3. https://openradar.appspot.com/33773917
4. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35827124
5. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35827113

## Similar issues with old Xcode 6/iOS 9 and Xcode 7/iOS 9

1. [Core Data - Failed to load optimized model at path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233939/core-data-failed-to-load-optimized-model-at-path)
2. [CoreData: Failed to load optimized model at path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715997/coredata-failed-to-load-optimized-model-at-path)
3. [Google Maps SDK for iOS Runtime warning - Core Date Failed to Load Optimised Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32847536/google-maps-sdk-for-ios-runtime-warning-core-date-failed-to-load-optimised-pat)

Comment: Hey, did you managed to fix it?

Comment: @DaNLtR, Not yet. I haven't observed crashes yet, planning to get back to it in a few days.

Comment: tnx:) googleMaps SDk crashes my ios 11 app with no reason!

Comment: I saw that warning over the weekend when doing some work on my app to update it (the current version works on iOS 11, but I wanted to start removing some deprecation warnings as the app was originally written for iOS 5). When I went to use the app today, it crashed when trying to open one of my core data files. I had a backup of the core data file (the app makes backups) and I was able to open it. Hopefully Apple can fix this soon. Glad I didn't make an update to the App Store!

Comment: Hi @DaveReed, Do you know (any link to info please) that's causing the apps to crash that were released with XCode 9 GM?

Comment: No, I don't have any more information than what's here. I saw this failed to load optimized model at path when compiling my app so googled the phrase and found this question.

Comment: @lal have you found any fix?

Comment: Haven't found a fix yet. Trying the new Xcode beta.

Comment: I am not getting callback (completion handler) from Google SDK when I call reverseGEO , is it related to this warning.

Comment: Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53973476/82813) to the linked question.

Answer (score 11):

The only way now to handle it (ios 11 = crash, not only warning) is to downgrade your sdk!!

Within your Podfile modify the following lines:

```
pod 'GoogleMaps', '2.2'
pod 'GooglePlaces', '2.2'
```

After doing so, run `pod update` so the library will get updated. 
any version above it will crash.

Update: try creating new target and run updated pod - worked for us

Comment: Also getting this on other frameworks (not GoogleMap) and with clean built app code. The logged warning has path that points to model used with app.

Comment: Also happens with xcode11 for frameworks: /Applications/Xcode11.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework

Answer (score 1):

The GoogleMaps 2.5.0 is out which is supposed to solve the issue.

Here is the issue tracker: [Crashes on iOS 11](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64504919)

just update your Podfile

```
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'GooglePlaces'
```

And pod update

I was getting these warnings on a simulator, after reverting my 'GoogleMaps' pod to 2.2 the API didn't show the map anymore. I updated to 2.5 which just got releases, the map works now but I still get these logs.

Also try a clean build! My app suddenly started crashing whenever I was opening a controller with GoogleMaps imported in it and everything was absolutely fine so I spent hours and finally just did a clean build and the issue was resolved!

```
command + shift + B
```

Comment: solved the issue for me but I still get the warnings. Try a clean build: command + shift + B

Comment: I having a similar issue, but not using pod 'Google....'. I am only using these pods 'Parse', 'Parse/UI' and 'SwiftSoup'.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading Xcode to Version 9.1 beta (9B46) doesn't output this warning in the console. Tried following to reproduce console message:

- Clean pods entirely, and rebuilt project.
- Complete Xcode clean including derived data, simulator cleanup.
- Device deployment, no crash observed.

Comment: Do you mean that there is no warning with Beta?

Comment: Updated the answer. Yes, there is no warning with 9.1 (9B46) beta.

Comment: :( I had the same issue with 9B46 version

Comment: @DJ-Glock, ahh :(. Is it your app or some framework that is resulting in error?

Comment: It's obviously my app, because error is related to my data model, new version of model.

Comment: Getting error and crash with 9B55. I have a versioned model and added a new version but still getting crash and console warning on device and crash no console warning on simulators.

Answer (score 0):

Performing a Clean Build Folder with Product->Clean Build Folder solved the issue for me in Xcode 11.5.  I wasnt using anything google related in my app and this problem just suddenly appeared.  Hopefully this helps someone.