# IOS 11 GoogleMaps crash on device (iphone 5s)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-maps, ios11

Xcode 8.3.2
iphone 5s ios 11
GoogleMaps 2.4

I getting error and crash in viewContoller

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: GMSMapView! 
override func viewDidLoad() { }
```

Logs:

```
CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2D2D05FB-A524-4594-B222-69B58E038E9A/Medico.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/Storage.omo'
CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2D2D05FB-A524-4594-B222-69B58E038E9A/Medico.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/Storage.omo'
CoreData: annotation:  Failed to load optimized model at path '/var/containers/Bundle/Application/2D2D05FB-A524-4594-B222-69B58E038E9A/Medico.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCacheStorage.momd/Storage.omo'
2017-09-21 16:02:08.805064+0300 Medico[2552:187180] [Common] _BSMachError: port 1187f; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14) "Unable to insert COPY_SEND"
```

It happens only in IOS 11

Comment: Are you running in the Simulator? It has been a known issue on it for a while. Try a real device.

Comment: Hey, Any solution ?

Comment: From crashLytics: Crashed: com.google.Maps.ResourceCache
EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x000000018113a7d4
gmscore::renderer::LoadPNGTexture(char const*, bool, gmscore::renderer::ResourceFinder*)

Comment: Facing the same issue, any workaround for that?

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46391213/4831936

downgrade your version to 2.2
you will still see warnings but no crash

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue before some days, actually this issue is related to xcode and/or debuger.

The workaround for this issue is as below:

- From the Menu in xcode, go to Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme..
- Select "Run" tab and then select "Options" sub-tab.
- Change "GPU Frame Capture" from "Automatically Enabled" or "OpenGL ES" to either "Metal" or "Disabled".

Thats it!!

Comment: Tried, didn't help :/

Comment: Is the said issue comes on simulator and real device both? Have you tried with both option "Metal" and "Disabled" in "GPU Frame Capture"?

Comment: Yea, Tried all, only downgrading my sdk worked, Tnx:)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your Xcode and Google maps SDK .it worked for me .

Comment: Can you share your xcode and google maps sdk versions?

Answer (score 0):

No need to upgrade Xcode. Just upgrade Google SDK. Had same problem. That helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to Google Maps SDK 2.5.0 and compile with Xcode 9.It will fix the issue.

https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/releases

Check 2.5.0 release notes.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you are only updating your sdk. Your pod repo is not updated.

**So first step is to update your pods by following command:**

> pod repo update

After that run:

> pod update

Once it is done install the pods again. Make sure your GoogleMap version should be 2.5.0. It should work!!